# Flask : TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Tags: python, flask

I have a generated flask application that is giving me this traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/.virtualenvs/j/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1701, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/.virtualenvs/j/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1689, in wsgi_app
    response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
  File "/home/.virtualenvs/j/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1687, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/.virtualenvs/j/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1360, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/.virtualenvs/j/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1358, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/.virtualenvs/j/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1344, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

but I cannot determine why or what is causing this at this point. The app starts and appears to run, but chokes on this traceback anytime I try to visit a route.

What is this and what would be causing this? I don't what object is a str and why it is not callable. This is the first I've seen something like this.

Comment: Can you show the function registered as a handler for the route you're trying to access?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That means that `self.view_functions[rule.endpoint]` is a string, not a function, thus cannot be called (with `(...)` operator). That said, it is difficult to tell what the issue without your code: Flask expects a function to be called and it gets a string. Did you use the `@app.route` decorator?

Try printing the value of `self.view_functions[rule.endpoint]` and see what comes out.

Comment: The routes are built outside of a route decorator from a different config within the blueprint that gets built and registered with the the application factory I built...when making a second application I did the route method notation as strings without thinking.

Answer (score 1):

This is, of course, one of these things that can have multiple different fixes (without seeing all of the original source code).

I got the same error in the HTML template that you did:

`TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`

My fix was to delete my (foolish) attempt to obtain the original request variables:

`my_form = request.form`

and just assign them by hand:

`my_form.blah = request.form['blah']`

Interestingly, the `my_form = request.form` executed without a problem, it only surfaced as an error in the HTML template.